# Javafx long touch hid touch square effects

Tags: javafx

i am creating a javafx application in which i am implementing touch pressed and release events. while long touch press a square box comes up as a effect for long touch event which doesn't go when i release the touch event. 
in the below image you can see square box is effect of touch event, when i randomly touch screen then it goes.
[image]

below is my touch listener code

```
javafx.event.EventHandler<TouchEvent> buttonStartZoomInPressed = new javafx.event.EventHandler<TouchEvent>(){ 
            public void handle(TouchEvent e) 
            { 
                startZoomIn();
            } 
        };
 buttonStartZoomIn.setOnTouchPressed(buttonStartZoomInPressed);
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] which demonstrates the problem. That said, the code you did provide doesn't show you listening for touch _released_ events...

Comment: @Slaw you can check it, just create a new application and create new empty Stage and run it, on the form give along touch press.

Comment: I don't have any touch-enabled devices. But regardless, are you saying the box shows up on _its own_ and that you did nothing to add it? Because that would have been clear from the start if you had provided a _[mre]_. I was under the impression the box  was added by you, possibly implemented in `startZoomIn()`.

Comment: no its like a effect of touch event it also happens with windows, in my windows if on the desktop i press touch for long  it shows the square box and opens up the right click menu, but when i release the touch square box also disappears. but it is not happening with the java fx form

Comment: Perhaps it's a bug in JavaFX, in which case you may consider submitting a bug report (don't forget a [mre]).